# TypeError: preprocess_input() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I was preprocessing the images as per the model’s requirement before passing input to the model.
I create the model as follows and I encounter the error.

```
TypeError: preprocess_input() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'
```

My code:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
X = preprocess_input(X, mode='tf')
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: This is because there is no `mode` parameter in `preprocess_input`. It has only two parameters i.e. `x=` and `data_format=`

Answer (score 0):

According to preprocess_input [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/preprocess_input), this function gets two arguments:

- input(X)
- data_format

you can use the following code:

```
X = preprocess_input(X, data_format=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted to

`tf.keras.applications.imagenet_utils.preprocess_input(X, data_format=None, mode='tf')`

and it is working for me.